# How to get the width of a mosaic window?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some css that needs to change, depending on the size of its containing mosaic window. I'm trying to get the width using `onResize` but that doesn't appear to be a thing.

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mosaic-simple-forked-ndjsc8?file=/src/MosaicApp.js

Look at line 27 of MosaicApp.js:

```js
onResize={(e)=>alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(e)))}
```